# Deserializing Slider Value

Tags: c#, json

I'm fairly new to C# and working with newtonsoft.json to save settings in a json file and load them on next startup, the saving slider value works, but loading doesn't. The error is:
System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'
Here's the code:

Main window:

```cs
public void SaveSettings()
{
    var settings = new Data.Settings
    {
        SongVolume = VolumeSlider.Value.ToString()
    };
    var stuffString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settings);
    File.WriteAllText(@".\utils\Settings.json", stuffString);
}

public void LoadSettings()
{
    if (!File.Exists(@".\utils\Settings.json"))
    {
        return;
    }

    var stuffString = File.ReadAllText(@".\utils\Settings.json");

    VolumeSlider.Value = (double)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stuffString);
}
```

The Data.Settings file:

```cs
public class Settings
{
    [JsonProperty("songVolume")]
    public string SongVolume { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to cast the full settings.json, which looks like `{"SongVolume": 123}`, into a double.

You'll need something like

```
public void LoadSettings()
{
    if (!File.Exists(@".\utils\Settings.json"))
    {
        return;
    }

    var stuffString = File.ReadAllText(@".\utils\Settings.json");
    var settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data.Settings>(stuffString);
    VolumeSlider.Value = Double.Parse(settings.SongVolume);
}
```

You might want to consider making the `SongVolume` property a `double` right away though, so you don't needlessly need to convert it to/from a string.